# KDE Konsole resize window with bash command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, kde

I'm trying to write a **bash**-script that resizes my **KDE-Konsole** terminal-window when started.
But I can't get it to work. **VT-Terminal-codes** don't seem to work properly.

`$ echo -e "\e[8;2;20t"` shrinks the used area of the terminal-window correctly, but leaves the window-size unchanged.

Is there any way to shrink the Konsole-window with a bash-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

First, what makes you think that these are DEC VT escape sequences?  A real terminal doesn't have a GUI window around it that can be resized.

What these are are escape sequences recognized by the `dtterm` terminal emulator, for window management, which the `xterm` terminal emulator supports for compatibility.

The `konsole` terminal emulator only supports supports *some* of what `xterm` supports.  It is not fully `xterm`-compatible let alone `dtterm`-compatible.  Specifically, in this case, it supports `CSI` `8` `;` *H* `;` *W* `t`, but not `CSI` `4` `;` *H* `;` *W* `t`.

### Further reading

- [`dtterm`(5)](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51_HTML/MAN/MAN5/0200____.HTM). *Tru64 UNIX Version 5.1 Section 5 Reference Pages*.  2000.  Compaq.
- Edward Moy, Stephen Gildea, Thomas Dickey (2014). [*XTerm Control Sequences*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#VT100%20Mode).  invisible-island.net.
- [`Vt102Emulation::processToken`](https://cgit.kde.org/konsole.git/tree/src/Vt102Emulation.cpp#n550).  *Vt102Emulation.cpp*.  Konsole.  KDE Project.

Comment: okay. so there is really no way of resizing a window? my question was not necessarily limited to escape-sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xdotool`](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml). I got it with `apt-get install xdotool` in Ubuntu.

The basic command may be something like:

```
xdotool windowsize `xdotool search Konsole` 60% 50%
```

This is only a starting point, far from being foolproof (e.g. if `xdotool search Konsole` doesn't return exactly one number then the outer command will break). Modify and expand it to your needs. In case you are not familiar with backtick, follow [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27428/108618).